# c++ - Receiving error "no matching function for call to pow(double)"

Tags: c++

I have following statement on

```
distance = sqrt (pow(point2X - point1X), 2) + (pow(point2Y - point1Y, 2));
```

this gives the following error

> error: no matching function for call to 'pow(double)'

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced a parenthesis. Should be:

```
distance = sqrt (pow(point2X - point1X, 2) + pow(point2Y - point1Y, 2));
```

A better way to express this is:

```
xdiff = point2X - point1X;
ydiff = point2Y - point1Y;
distance = std::sqrt( xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff);
```

If you have C++11, you can use `std::hypot`

```
distance = std::hypot ( point2X - point1X,  point2Y - point1Y );
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't be this. This is obviously not the correct formula for the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I originally only corrected for syntax. I edited my answer to correct for semantics as well.